# How can I create a clickable windows app link in spotify?

Tags: python

In a piece of code I am working on, I have created 2 ways to print the link for a song on spotify, should it exist. The first of which gives the link to the web based player, the second gives the format for a link that will try to open an installed app. However, only the printed link for the web player is clickable, as it is a `http://www.` type of link. Is there a way to format the print function to turn it into a link, so that way I could click on it in the output and try to open the spotify app?

```
try:
        print("Spotify Web Player: " + "https://open.spotify.com/track/" + data['metadata']['music'][0]['external_metadata']['spotify']['track']['id'])
        print("Spotify App: " + "spotify:track:" + data['metadata']['music'][0]['external_metadata']['spotify']['track']['id'])
```

Note, the direct app link looks like this, and if you paste it into the URL bar, it asks to open the app: `spotify:track:60jpDubMmVyR5molJp2TCm`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the `os` module built into Python:

```
import os

os.startfile("spotify:track:60jpDubMmVyR5molJp2TCm")
```

This will successfully open the song inside of Spotify.